# Copying random text from a notepad file in Python

Tags: python, html, forms, web

I'm trying to write a python script to fill out a web form, submit it, and then repeat the process.

Now I have a `.txt` file which has text which is to be entered into the text fields onto the page. For example, I have a field named "Title", so I want my script to randomly select any one of the titles that I have in my text file and fill that particular field with that.

[Here's](http://lucknow.quikr.com/post-classifieds-ads/?postadcategoryid=18222211855) the web form I'm trying to fill 
I only need to fill a few of the fields on the given page, like title, description etc. and upload a photo also. If you'll see the page you'll get the idea of what I'm talking about.

So how can I chose random lines from my text file and put them into their respective fields on the web form. Also, how do I upload the image?

Comment: Please be more specific about what your actual problem is? Submitting the web form? selecting random lines?

Comment: @languitar Question edited

Comment: i think python's Selenium module can help you for this.

Comment: @Rednivrug would you please elaborate//